# MouseWheel event doesn't fire when using any control with scrolbars (in C# Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, events, scrollbar, mousewheel

MouseWheel event doesn't fire 
when I' am using any control (ListBox, Panel, TextBox) with scrollbars.

To reproduce problem:

```
public class Form1 : Form
 {
  private readonly Button button1;
  private readonly TextBox textBox1;

  private void button1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
   ToString(); // doesn't fire when uncomment lines below
  }

  public Form1()
  {
   button1 = new Button();
   textBox1 = new TextBox();
   SuspendLayout();

   button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(80, 105);
   button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
   button1.MouseWheel += button1_MouseWheel;
   button1.Click += button1_Click;

   textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(338, 105);
   //textBox1.Multiline = true; // uncomment this
   //textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;  // uncomment this 
   textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 92);

   ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(604, 257);
   Controls.Add(textBox1);
   Controls.Add(button1);
   ResumeLayout(false);
   PerformLayout();
  }

  // Clicking the button sets Focus, but even I do it explicit Focus() or Select()
  // still doesn't work
  private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
   button1.Focus();
   button1.Select();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the mouse, 
I use "Lenovo USB Optical Wheel Mouse"
(default configuration
"Whell Button" function "Quick/AutoScroll")

Comment: I use: Windows Vista Buisness, .Net Framework 3.5 SP1, Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition (all official hotfixes). Build Debug: Target Framework = .Net Framework 3.5, Output type = Windows Application

Comment: Mouse Configuration:
Control Panel/Mouse/Wheel/Whell->Enable Universal Scrolling;
Control Panel/Mouse/Wheel/Whell Button->Quick/AutoScrol;
Control Panel/Mouse/Wheel/Scrolling Speed->Scroll=10 line(s) per noth;

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. I think many people confuse it with the "focused vs. hovered over" problematics. I have same ScrollableControl-based control which either triggers OnMouseWheel or doesn't, depending on whether it is displaying scrollbars currently or not. I think scrollbars somehow capture the wheel events, but I didn't study the issue enough yet. Did OP find a solution by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found solution**, gility is default "Mouse Configuration". *Lenovo USB Optical Wheel Mouse* default configuration is:

Control Panel/Mouse/Wheel/Whell->**Enable Universal Scrolling**;

I changed to:

Control Panel/Mouse/Wheel/Whell->**Use Microsoft Office 97 Scrolling Emulation Only**

Now in .net code MouseWheel working with **Focused** *Control*.

---

But questions are:

- how can I fix it in .net code?
- how can I detect this situation in .net code?

Any ideas ?

Comment: Use Spy++ and check which messages are being sent to the controls.

Answer (score 15):

I was having the same problem, and what worked for me was to add a handler for the event MouseEnter in the control, that one is triggered with or without focus.

```
private void chart1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Focus();
}
```

After that I could get the mouseWheel events with no problems.

Comment: Strangely, on one W10 compu the identical program did mousewheel, on the other it didn't, until I used your solution.

Comment: I have notified similar discrepancies between Windows 7 and 10 : the former will send mouse wheel events to active control only (eg: combobox) while second will send those events to control which is under mouse (eg: panel). Additionally, In Windows 7 if no control has focus, mouse wheel events are sent to main form.

Answer (score 2):

You normally need to make sure the control you want to handle the MouseWheel event is active.

For example try calling `button1.Select()` in the Form Load (or Shown) event and then using the scroll wheel.

eg:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(button1_MouseWheel);

    button1.Select();  
}
```

Comment: Still nothing, same problem,it is very strange, but in my case it doesn't work. Even I set Focus or Select, and Cursor is over the buton1, when I use mouse wheel, it scrolls textbox1 (sic!)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example, and, whether the lines were commented or not, the MouseWheel event only fires if the button is focused.  This behavior is by design.  (the `MouseWheel` event, like keyboard events, goes to the focused control)

Comment: I read about i documentation but, it is very strange, 
but in my case it doesn't work:
I add to code:

public Form1()
{
  (...)
  button1.Click += button1_Click;
  (...)
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  button1.Focus();
}


Not working, even I set Focus, and Cursor is over the buton1, 
when I use mouse wheel, it scrolls textbox1 (sic!)