# Raising mouse wheel event on picture box in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

After looking at [Mousewheel event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782763/mousewheel-event-not-firing) and at [MouseWheel event doesn't fire when using any control with scrolbars (in C# Windows Forms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094378/mousewheel-event-doesnt-fire-when-using-any-control-with-scrolbars-in-c-sharp) and at [MouseWheel Event With Picturebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399666/mousewheel-event-with-picturebox), I have coded the following fragment which, well .... doesn't work (i.e., mouse wheel won't fire in VS2013, Win7, x64). Appericate any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace MyWinForm
{
    class Program
    {
        private Form theForm;
        private PictureBox thePictureBox;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Program theProgram = new Program();
            Application.Run(theProgram.theForm);

        }

        Program()
        {
            theForm = new Form();
            thePictureBox = new PictureBox();
            theForm.Controls.Add(thePictureBox);
            thePictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\cameraman.bmp");
            thePictureBox.Width = theImage.Width;
            thePictureBox.Height = theImage.Height;
            thePictureBox.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(this.PictureBox_MouseWheel);
            thePictureBox.MouseHover += new EventHandler(this.PictureBox_MouseHover);

        }

        private void PictureBox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2 + 2 = 5");//Will never get here....

        }
        private void PictureBox_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            thePictureBox.Focus();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code works perfectly fine when I try it

Comment: how did you test it?

Comment: Ctrl+F5 -> Attach to process-> breakpoint in mousewheel callback doesn't get hit when wheeling mouse over the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me with mouseMove instead of mousehover:

```
        pictureBox1.MouseMove += newEventHandler(this.PictureBox_MouseHover);
```

Just change the name now from Hover to move so it makes sense:p

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else is looking for the solution.
To make the pictureBox1 fire MouseWheel event I added a MouseEnter event:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

MouseWheel event is center mouse event. You have to scroll center mouse then MouseWheel event will be handled.